# Silent sfdx Deploy Failure

Tags: lightning-web-components

Against my better judgment I upgraded my DX environment recently with - sfdx update.  Now deploy is broken.  No error visible and no error log created.  Ugh.

[image]

Here is my current setup

```
PS C:\Users\Dave2\Documents\Visual Studio Code\TMS> sfdx plugins --core
@oclif/plugin-autocomplete 0.3.0 (core)
@oclif/plugin-commands 1.3.0 (core)
@oclif/plugin-help 3.2.2 (core)
@oclif/plugin-not-found 1.2.4 (core)
@oclif/plugin-plugins 1.10.1 (core)
@oclif/plugin-update 1.4.0-3 (core)
@oclif/plugin-warn-if-update-available 1.7.0 (core)
@oclif/plugin-which 1.0.3 (core)
@salesforce/sfdx-diff 0.0.6
@salesforce/sfdx-plugin-lwc-test 0.1.7 (core)
@salesforce/sfdx-trust 3.6.0 (core)
alias 1.1.10 (core)
apex 0.2.3 (core)
auth 1.7.1 (core)
config 1.2.14 (core)
custom-metadata 1.0.12 (core)
data 0.6.0 (core)
generator 1.1.7 (core)
limits 1.2.1 (core)
org 1.6.7 (core)
salesforce-alm 52.2.3 (core)
schema 1.0.8 (core)
sfdx-cli 7.112.1 (core)
source 1.0.6 (core)
telemetry 1.2.3 (core)
templates 52.1.0 (core)
user 1.4.0 (core)
```

How do I even begin to attack this issue?  There is no log file generated....  Should I back out to a previous release?  Any help is greatly appreciated.  This was working fine until the last sfdx update.

Thanks.

Adding the error log:

```
{"name":"sfdx","hostname":"DESKTOP-Q4TJUS0","pid":15168,"log":"SfdxProjectJson","level":40,"msg":"The config file: C:\\Users\\Dave2\\.sfdx\\sfdx-project.json is not schema valid\nDue to: Validation errors:\nshould have required property 'packageDirectories'","time":"2021-08-06T18:20:53.547Z","v":0}
{"name":"sfdx","hostname":"DESKTOP-Q4TJUS0","pid":15168,"log":"SfdxProjectJson","level":40,"msg":"The config file: C:\\Users\\Dave2\\.sfdx\\sfdx-project.json is not schema valid\nDue to: Validation errors:\nshould have required property 'packageDirectories'","time":"2021-08-06T18:20:53.556Z","v":0}
{"name":"sfdx","hostname":"DESKTOP-Q4TJUS0","pid":15168,"log":"Deploy","level":50,"msg":"[\n  '\\x1B[1mERROR running force:source:deploy: \\x1B[22m',\n  '\\x1B[31mDeploy failed.\\x1B[39m'\n]","time":"2021-08-06T18:26:52.047Z","v":0}
```

So the problem is it is looking for sfdx-project.json in the wrong place:

C:\Users\Dave2.sfdx\sfdx-project.json

Why is it looking there now instead of the project directory where it's always been in the past??

Here is where it is now.  Why is it not looking here for it??

[image]

Comment: I feel ya. I vaguely recall a "phantom" failure like that happening to us last year, but I can't remember what we did to get past it. If you change the `--loglevel` to TRACE or DEBUG, does it generate a log file?

Comment: Not really an answer, but when I've encountered this (deploying between sandboxes), I've just re-run the deployment and it seems to work on the second or third attempt. Not really an option if it's taking hours to run your tests, but it could be workable for some.

Comment: Thanks guys,  Seeing a log with "debug" level.  Will dig into that and see what I can find.

Comment: Added the error log and additional info above.

Comment: I haven't processed your additions/edits yet; but did you verify in your org that the deploy did, indeed, actually fail?

Comment: Yes, verified.  I am able to save-and-build individual classes, no problem.  But the command line deploy fails (nothing in audit trail on org.)

Comment: We were in a similar situation after sfdx update. So what we did - after triggering sfdx deploy from command line and getting error, we logged right into target org (sandbox in our case), navigated to Setup -> Deployments, and checked recently failed deployment job - there was an actual error message there. In our case, for some reason sfdx was trying to deploy lwc stubs folder and was complaining re invalid lwc component descriptor - was working fine with previous sfdx version. Hope it helps figure out your issue.

Comment: Wesaw - This is very helpful.  I did not realize that the log of errors it out there in the org.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up deleting the project folder and rebuilding the project from GIT/VSCode.  Fixed the problem although I do not know what it was...

Comment: The sfdx team broke the sfdx install for all developers, and didn't take responsibility for it, you wouldn't know it happened unless you read the github issues, such as https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues/1104

Comment: Ugh.  Thanks for the backstory.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue.  Interestingly this was only happening when I tried to deploy to one sandbox and not others.

I ended up rearranging sfdx-project.json and it fixed the issue.

From this:

```
{
  "packageDirectories": [
    {
      "path": "force-app",
      "default": true
    }
  ],
  "name": "Rice_EmployeePortal",
  "namespace": "",
  "sfdcLoginUrl": "https://login.salesforce.com",
  "sourceApiVersion": "53.0"
}
```

To this:

```
{
  "name": "Rice_EmployeePortal",
  "namespace": "",
  "sfdcLoginUrl": "https://login.salesforce.com",
  "sourceApiVersion": "53.0",
  "packageDirectories": [
    {
      "path": "force-app",
      "default": true
    }
  ]
}
```